# Pigeonhole Principle - n people in a room

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Given the following description: There are $n$ students are in a lecture hall. Two students $i$ and $j$ either know each other or they don't know the other. Let $p$, $q$ be two students who have the same number of acquaintances this way. The sets of acquaintances of $p$ and $q$ are disjunct.

Now I want to prove that either no student knows any other student or at least one student knows exactly one student.

I really want to prove it myself but I currently don't see how... Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I clarified it. Yes. Either all n students have no acquaintances or at least one student has exactly one acquaintance.

Comment: Now... if $p$ and $q$ can be arbitrarily selected, and we are interested only in this specific choice of $p,q$, consider where you have five students... $A,B,C,p,q$ where $A,B,C$ all know eachother and don't know either of $p,q$ and $p,q$ are both entirely alone and know no one.  (*I.e. a triangle and two isolated vertices*).  Here we have a situation where our graph has at least one edge (*and so doesn't fall into the first case*) while also having no person with only one acquaintance.

Comment: Do you perhaps then mean to have the condition that for *all* choices of $p,q$ that if $\deg(p)=\deg(q)$ then $\mathcal{N}(p)\cap \mathcal{N}(q)=\emptyset$?  (*i.e. if $p,q$ have the same number of acquaintances that they share none*)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  you want to prove that not everybody has at least two acquaintances.  Assume they do.  The range of number of acquaintances is at most $2$ to $n-1$, so there must be either three people with the same number or two pairs with the same number each.  In any case, nobody can have more than $n-3$ as they must miss two of these people.  Now you need more matches in number of acquaintances, which reduces the maximum number for one person even further.  Eventually you run out of room.

Comment: So basically I can say that if student $s$ has two acquaintances, then those two must have different numbers of acquaintances, so at least one has greater or equal 3 acquaintances and if I iterate this until n-1, one of those n-1 acquaintances must have n themselves, which obviously is a contradiction?

Comment: That is a different approach than I was thinking of, but it works, too and seems simpler.  I was bringing down the maximum number of acquaintances anybody could have.